Retrieve & Set "KeepWithNext" / "KeepNext" Property for a "Table" in Word using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing
I've inserted a table in a word document and have applied the Paragraph Style "Keep With Next" for the table (only) as true, so that in case the table data splits between pages, then the table will be shifted to the next page.
Now I need to copy this content from the source document to the destination document using "DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing" library.
The additional logic that I need to implement is that, if in the Source document, "Keep With Next" paragraph property for the Table (only) is checked, then in the Destination document, "Keep With Next" paragraph property for the Table (only) will be unchecked (& vice-versa). So I need to read the property value from Source Document for the table (only) and set the same in the Destination document for the table (only).
I was able to do the same with Micrsoft.Office.Interop but I need to implement it with "DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing".
So help would be appreciated.
The attached picture is the steps I'm following to check the "Keep With Next" paragraph property of the "table" in the Source document.
(https://i.sstatic.net/JzFOSX2C.jpg)
I've inserted a table in a word document and have applied the Paragraph Style "Keep With Next" for the table (only) as true, so that in case the table data splits between pages, then the table will be shifted to the next page.
Now I need to copy this content from the source document to the destination document using "DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing" library.
The additional logic that I need to implement is that, if in the Source document, "Keep With Next" paragraph property for the Table (only) is checked, then in the Destination document, "Keep With Next" paragraph property for the Table (only) will be unchecked (& vice-versa). So I need to read the property value from Source Document for the table (only) and set the same in the Destination document for the table (only).
I was able to do the same with Micrsoft.Office.Interop but I need to implement it with "DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing" as the "KeepNext" property of the latter library is not working.
So help would be appreciated.
